# How can I write a simple JScript input/output program?

Tags: javascript, wsh, jscript

I'm planning on using JavaScript to enter an informatics competition (BIO) tomorrow. However, I can't rely on the examiner having a browser with a decent JavaScript engine, so I was hoping to use Microsoft's JScript instead.

However, the documentation is, quite frankly, crap. Can someone post some example code that reads in a line of text, calls `foo(string)` on it, and echos the output to the command line?

Similarly, how do I actually run it? Will `wscript.exe PATH_TO_JS_FILE` do the trick?

Comment: +1, the documentation is so crappy that it makes actual crap look ok.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using the command-line, I'd execute the script using `CSCRIPT.EXE`.
ie: `CSCRIPT.EXE myscript.js`
This is because `WScript.Echo` from `WSCRIPT` will create a dialog box and from `CSCRIPT` outputs a line to the console. Run this in a command window (CMD).

Reading a line from console into variable:

```
var x = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
```

Where `StdIn` is a [TextStream object](https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/objects-textstream.html). There is also an `StdOut` which can be used in place of `WScript.Echo()`...

Writing the output of `foo(x)` to console: (must run under `CSCRIPT`)

```
WScript.Echo(foo(x));
```

You can use the `WScript` object to determine which engine you are running under, there's a question/answer for that (VBScript, but uses the same objects under JScript) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5219524/76840).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be sure your program only runs in the command line, you may use the `WScript.StdIn` and `WScript.StdOut` objects/properties:

```
var myString = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(myString);
```

and run it with `cscript.exe`. But if you want it to be a GUI program, it is a bit more difficult considering that JScript doesn't have a native `InputBox` function like `VBScript`. However, as described [here](http://wsh2.uw.hu/ch08c.html) we may use [Windows Script Host (WSH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host). Create a `.wsf` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<job id="testJScriptInputBox">
    <script language="VBScript">
    <![CDATA[
        Function WSHInputBox(Message, Title, Value)
            WSHInputBox = InputBox(Message, Title, Value)
        End Function
    ]]>
    </script>

    <script language="JScript">
    <![CDATA[
        var vbOKOnly = 0;                // Constants for Popup
        var vbInformation = 64;

        var title = "InputBox function for JScript";
        var prompt = "Enter a string: ";

        var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");

        var result = WSHInputBox(prompt, title, "New York");

        if (result != null)   
        {  // Cancel wasn't clicked, so get input.
            var intDoIt =  WshShell.Popup(result,
                                          0,
                                          "Result",
                                          vbOKOnly + vbInformation);
        }
        else
        { // Cancel button was clicked.
            var intDoIt =  WshShell.Popup("Sorry, no input",
                                          0,
                                          "Result",
                                          vbOKOnly + vbInformation);
        }                           

    ]]>
    </script>
</job>
```

and run it with either `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`. Alternatively, you could also use [HTML Application (HTA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) to create more elaborate GUIs.