# Get command line arguments with jscript.net

Tags: .net, jscript, jscript.net

None of these work:

```
var arguments = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

~

```
var arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

~

```
var arguments:String[] = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

~

```
var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

it prints `JS1135: Variable 'System' has not been declared` or `error JS1135: Variable 'Environment' has not been declared` . [Even in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  there's no example with jscript. Is is possible to get the arguments in jscript.net ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
import System;

var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
print(arguments[0]);
print(arguments[1]);
```

Though the `arguments[0]` is always the name of the compiled/called .exe file.