# javascript as exe file without node it is possible to input value

Tags: javascript

[here is site about how to make from javascript file.exe](http://www.phpied.com/make-your-javascript-a-windows-exe/)

is it possible to enter text into a command prompt and return entered text? But wihout use node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get command line arguments with jscript.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015121/get-command-line-arguments-with-jscript-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been out of Windows development for a while but I assume the mechanics are still the same. The command line arguements should be in the Argument Collections.

Here is an article on an older scripting guide that should get you going in the right direction.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156618.aspx