# Can I use plain JavaScript (no html composition) to read a value from console? (like in Java and C++)

Tags: javascript, input, console

This is a class project, the teacher will accept only one (.js) file as the submit. 
In the project, I will need to read command from the console and react to it. Is that possible in js? I have tried event, however it seems like must base on html components.

Comment: Sure. You have to run JS on the console and read the standard input. The Node docs cover most of that, I believe.

Comment: So this is talking about something he can run the browser? Or is this something that can be run with Node?

Comment: So I need to use Node.js is that right?

Comment: On Windows the Scripting Host can do this, E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441003/how-can-i-write-a-simple-jscript-input-output-program

Answer (score 0):

The read input from the command line, the prompt module of nodejs is nice :

```
var prompt = require('prompt')

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    log.error(err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
})

prompt.message = "> ".green;
prompt.delimiter = "";

var properties = [{
    name: 'login',
    message: 'login: '.white
}];

function onErr(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return 1;
}

function start () {

    prompt.start();

    prompt.get(properties, function (err, input) {
        if (err) {
            return onErr(err);
        }
        console.log("hello",input.login)
    });
}

start()
```

see https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt

Comment: Thank you for the replay, since JS is really not suitable for such a mission We decided to use Java.