# One WSH JScript instance to communicate to the StdIn and StdOut of another instance

Tags: windows, jscript, wsh

I want a JScript instance to send a string to the StdIn of another JScript instance; let the other one processes it and then read the returned StdOut results. Consider the code block below:

```js
// script_zero.js
var objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell");

var objExec = objShell.Exec("%comspec% /c script_one.bat");

objExec.StdIn.Write("some random string");

WScript.StdOut.Write(objExec.StdOut.ReadAll());
```

and

```vb
rem script_one.bat
@echo off
set /p userInput=
echo %userInput%
```

which works perfectly fine, returning

> some random string

if I run `cscript //E:JScript //Nologo script_zero.js`.

However, if I change the second line to

```js
var objExec = objShell.Exec("%comspec% /c cscript //E:JScript //Nologo script_two.js");
```

So it can call the JScript

```js
// script_two.js
var InputLine = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(InputLine);
```

It gets stuck, presumably the called script waiting for input. Although `script_one.bat` and `script_two.js` seem identical in their functionality. I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I write a simple JScript input/output program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441003/how-can-i-write-a-simple-jscript-input-output-program)

Answer (score -1):

OK, it seems that changing the last two lines of the `script_zero.js` to

```js
objExec.StdIn.WriteLine("some random string");

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(objExec.StdOut.ReadLine());
```

solves the problem. But I'll wait for others to propose better solutions.