# How to return result from JavaScript action in Power Automate Desktop?

Tags: javascript, jscript, power-automate-desktop

If I use a flow action **Run JavaScript function on web page** in Power Automate Desktop, I am able to use following code:

```
function ExecuteScript() { 
  alert('foo');              // shown as pop up messag 
  console.log('baa');  // goes to browser dev tools console
  return 'result'         // stored as output variable of the flow action
}
```

and see the return value as value of the output variable

[image]

However, if I use the same code for a flow action **Run JavaScript**, the value of the output variable is not set.

**=> How to return a result from the the "Run JavaScript" flow action?**

Answer (score 0):

The **Run JavaScript** action uses a different language then the **Run JavaScript function on web page**. It uses [JScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//hbxc2t98(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), an ECMAscript based dialect from Microsoft. (In my opinion the action should be called "Run JScript" to avoid confusion.).

**a)** In order to return a value from the action use [WScript.echo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//h8f603s7(v=vs.85))

```
WScript.echo("result")
```

**b)** The result variable might contain an additional **CRLF** that needs to be considered when processing the result in further actions.

**c)** If you want to be able to show/handle **errors**, you need to enable the `%ScriptError%` variable, which is disabled by default. Also see related question

[How to show/handle errors thrown while running JavaScript flow actions in Power Automate Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77736776/how-to-show-handle-errors-thrown-while-running-javascript-flow-actions-in-power)

**Sources:**

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Desktop/Executing-JavaScript/td-p/865149

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/scripting#working-with-variables-in-scripting-actions

**Related:**

[How can I write a simple JScript input/output program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441003/how-can-i-write-a-simple-jscript-input-output-program)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms950396(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference