# How to show/handle errors thrown while running JavaScript flow actions in Power Automate Desktop?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, jscript, power-automate-desktop

The documentation about script actions states, that a variable `ScriptError` is produced:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/scripting#variables-produced-2

However, when trying to display that Variable using a **Display message** flow action or **Set variable** flow action, I get the error

```
Variable 'ScriptError' does not exist.
```

I also tried the flow action **On block error** to handle errors thrown by a JavaScript/JScript action. The script runs silently without showing any error.

**=> How to show/handle errors for script actions in Power Automate Desktop?**

**Related:**

[How to return result from JavaScript action in Power Automate Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77736632/how-to-return-result-from-javascript-action-in-power-automate-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `%ScriptError%` is disabled by default. Once it has been enabled in the section `Variables produced` of the options, it can be used as expected:

[image]